# knockout.js and rails 3.1 using the knockout-rails gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, knockout.js

I've successfully tied my rails model to my knockout.js viewModel, but because the way it applies the bindings like so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function(){
    // Create the viewModel with prefilled data
    window.hud = new Hud(<%=raw @hud.to_json %>);
    ko.applyBindings(window.hud); // And bind everything
  });
</script>
```

I'm not sure as to where or how I apply ko.computed() on my fields.  The Knockout-Rails gem makes it so all my database fields have a ko.observable() attached to them, but I just can't figure out how to use ko.computed() on certain fields instead.

I'm still really new to knockout.js, so sorry if this doesn't make a whole lot of sense, if more detail is needed, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out, I just ended up directly accessing my fields with window.hud.<field name> to set the ko.computed on it and worked like a charm.

Comment: can you give an example/show code.  Thanks.

Comment: @Digi_Cazter... till waiting for an example :-)

Comment: The company I work for scrapped using knockout.js, but it's funny cause as of today the solution they created in its place has reached a dead end as it has become too cumbersome to maintain.  So to my point, they are letting me go back to using knockout.js again.  I'm working on the mock up for it right now. I don't have the original code as of the original date of this post so I'm starting from the ground up, but I will post what my solution is once I get to that point again. Probably a day or two.

Comment: @Digi_Cazter... thanks, looking forward to seeing what you come up with